# shell command for SmoothImage.cxx from ANTs library

Tags: c++, bash, shell

I have the code below which I would like to run it from a bash script in ubuntu. Inside my bash script, I wrote the command below.

```
$DOANTS/SmoothImage $216*512*512 $RESULTS/Registration/NiftyReg/StructureGuided/Pat28_MLAF0113_pv_Aff_BSpline_Iso_ArgMax.nii.gz $1 $RESULTS/Registration/NiftyReg/StructureGuided/Pat28_${CASES[$i]}\_Prostate_Aff_BSpline_Iso_ArgMax_smoothed.nii.gz
```

but I get the following error:

```
Unsupported dimension
```

I am not sure why the dimension is not passed. would be thankful if you could let me know the reason. The true size of image is. `216*512*512`

The code is as below:

```
    #include "antsUtilities.h"
#include <algorithm>

#include "itkMedianImageFilter.h"
#include "itkDiscreteGaussianImageFilter.h"
#include "ReadWriteData.h"

namespace ants
{
template <unsigned int ImageDimension>
int SmoothImage(int argc, char *`1  [])
{
  typedef float                                                           PixelType;
  typedef itk::Image<PixelType, ImageDimension>                           ImageType;

  std::vector<float> sigmaVector = ConvertVector<float>( argv[3] );

  typename ImageType::Pointer image1 = ITK_NULLPTR;
  typename ImageType::Pointer varimage = ITK_NULLPTR;
  ReadImage<ImageType>(image1, argv[2]);

  typedef itk::DiscreteGaussianImageFilter<ImageType, ImageType> dgf;
  typedef itk::MedianImageFilter<ImageType, ImageType>           medf;
  typename dgf::Pointer filter = dgf::New();
  typename medf::Pointer filter2 = medf::New();
  bool usespacing = false;
  if( argc  >  5 )
    {
    usespacing = atoi(argv[5]);
    }
  bool usemedian = false;
  if( argc  >  6 )
    {
    usemedian = atoi(argv[6]);
    }
  if( !usespacing )
    {
    filter->SetUseImageSpacingOff();
    }
  else
    {
    filter->SetUseImageSpacingOn();
    }

  if( !usemedian )
    {
    if( sigmaVector.size() == 1 )
      {
      filter->SetVariance( vnl_math_sqr( sigmaVector[0] ) );
      }
    else if( sigmaVector.size() == ImageDimension )
      {
      typename dgf::ArrayType varianceArray;
      for( unsigned int d = 0; d < ImageDimension; d++ )
        {
        varianceArray[d] = vnl_math_sqr( sigmaVector[d] );
        }
      filter->SetVariance( varianceArray );
      }
    else
      {
      std::cerr << "Incorrect sigma vector size.  Must either be of size 1 or ImageDimension." << std::endl;
      }
    filter->SetMaximumError( 0.01f );
    filter->SetInput( image1 );
    filter->Update();
    varimage = filter->GetOutput();
    }
  else
    {
    typename ImageType::SizeType rad;
    if( sigmaVector.size() == 1 )
      {
      rad.Fill( static_cast<unsigned long>( sigmaVector[0] ) );
      }
    else if( sigmaVector.size() == ImageDimension )
      {
      for( unsigned int d = 0; d < ImageDimension; d++ )
        {
        rad[d] = sigmaVector[d];
        }
      }
    else
      {
      std::cerr << "Incorrect sigma vector size.  Must either be of size 1 or ImageDimension." << std::endl;
      }
    filter2->SetRadius(rad);
    filter2->SetInput( image1 );
    filter2->Update();
    varimage = filter2->GetOutput();
    }
  WriteImage<ImageType>( varimage, argv[4] );
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// entry point for the library; parameter 'args' is equivalent to 'argv' in (argc,argv) of commandline parameters to
// 'main()'
int SmoothImage( std::vector<std::string> args, std::ostream* /*out_stream = NULL */ )
{
  // put the arguments coming in as 'args' into standard (argc,argv) format;
  // 'args' doesn't have the command name as first, argument, so add it manually;
  // 'args' may have adjacent arguments concatenated into one argument,
  // which the parser should handle
  args.insert( args.begin(), "SmoothImage" );

  int     argc = args.size();
  char* * argv = new char *[args.size() + 1];
  for( unsigned int i = 0; i < args.size(); ++i )
    {
    // allocate space for the string plus a null character
    argv[i] = new char[args[i].length() + 1];
    std::strncpy( argv[i], args[i].c_str(), args[i].length() );
    // place the null character in the end
    argv[i][args[i].length()] = '\0';
    }
  argv[argc] = ITK_NULLPTR;
  // class to automatically cleanup argv upon destruction
  class Cleanup_argv
  {
public:
    Cleanup_argv( char* * argv_, int argc_plus_one_ ) : argv( argv_ ), argc_plus_one( argc_plus_one_ )
    {
    }

    ~Cleanup_argv()
    {
      for( unsigned int i = 0; i < argc_plus_one; ++i )
        {
        delete[] argv[i];
        }
      delete[] argv;
    }

private:
    char* *      argv;
    unsigned int argc_plus_one;
  };
  Cleanup_argv cleanup_argv( argv, argc + 1 );

  // antscout->set_stream( out_stream );

  if( argc < 4 )
    {
    std::cout << "Usage:  " << std::endl;
    std::cout << argv[0]
             <<
      " ImageDimension image.ext smoothingsigma outimage.ext {sigma-is-in-spacing-coordinates-0/1} {medianfilter-0/1}"
             << std::endl;
    std::cout << " if median, then sigma means radius of filtering " << std::endl;
    std::cout << " A separate sigma can be specified for each dimension, e.g., 1.5x1x2 " << std::endl;
    if( argc >= 2 &&
        ( std::string( argv[1] ) == std::string("--help") || std::string( argv[1] ) == std::string("-h") ) )
      {
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
      }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  switch( atoi(argv[1]) )
    {
    case 2:
      {
      return SmoothImage<2>(argc, argv);
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      {
      return SmoothImage<3>(argc, argv);
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      {
      return SmoothImage<4>(argc, argv);
      }
      break;
    default:
      std::cout << "Unsupported dimension" << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
} // namespace ants
enter code here
```

Comment: Check out the "parameters" section in the bash manpage. Also, is that a [mcve]? In any case, the error seems to come from your code, so why don't you put some diagnostic outputs in there or run it in a debugger?

Comment: No. Look at the very end of the C++. The first parameter is meant to be a selector between 1 and 4 - the "dimension" value. The first parameter above is "$216*512*512". Two problem, the $2 is meant to be the second parameter of the calling script, so what is intended is "$2 16*512*512". However "16*512*512" needs to be resolved separately (or in a subscript or something), because bash doesn't do command line math that way.

Comment: It's really hard to know what the minimum reproducible example is when you don't know what the source of a problem is, but the problem with throwing in everything and hoping someone spots the problem is that even the best analyst can get lost while trying to untangle your whole C++ program as well as considering where it might be going wrong. Just a suggestion - when mysterious things are happening with your parameters, just add some statements like std::cout << "param 1 = " << argv[1]; and so forth. In this case, it would have popped off the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you're making an assumption that bash does inline math on the command line. It doesn't. Try for example -

```
$ echo $216*512*512
$ 16*512*512
```

In fact, unless I'm missing some syntactic magic of which I'm unaware, the $2 is simply being interpreted as the second parameter to the parent script, as in -

```
$ function check() {   echo $216*512*512; }
$ check fragile rock
$ rock16*512*512
```

See? However, I think what you've got here is a typo. The $2 was probably meant to be by itself, because the first parameter to your program is a selector that you use near the end to instantiate the templated version of your smoothing function. So, the second parameter to the calling script becomes the first parameter of `SmoothImage`, as in -

```
$DOANTS/SmoothImage $2 16*512*512 $RESULTS/Registration/NiftyReg/StructureGuided/Pat28_MLAF0113_pv_Aff_BSpline_Iso_ArgMax.nii.gz $1 $RESULTS/Registration/NiftyReg/StructureGuided/Pat28_${CASES[$i]}\_Prostate_Aff_BSpline_Iso_ArgMax_smoothed.nii.gz
```

If however, as you say, the size parameter is 16*512*512 or 216*512*512 as the case may be, you're still running into the problem that bash doesn't do math in that way on the command line. What you want is something like -

```
declare -ri size=16*512*512
# or just "let size=16*512*512", the "declare -ri" just makes it a read-only integer
$DOANTS/SmoothImage $2 $size $RESULTS/Registration/NiftyReg/StructureGuided/Pat28_MLAF0113_pv_Aff_BSpline_Iso_ArgMax.nii.gz $1 $RESULTS/Registration/NiftyReg/StructureGuided/Pat28_${CASES[$i]}\_Prostate_Aff_BSpline_Iso_ArgMax_smoothed.nii.gz
```

I think that's where you're headed. If you want some evidence that this works, on your bash command line, try -

```
$ let size=16*512*512
$ echo $size
$ 4194304
```

Your C++ is probably fine (though I haven't gone through it in detail, but at a glance it looks OK). The problem is your bash. If you want features like inline math, you might consider looking at Python to drive your C++ programs. Just a thought.